# Link file without uploading in capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Whenever I add a file to `:linked_files` in `deploy.rb`, it's both uploaded to the shared dir and linked to from the current. I'd like to keep using the [linked-files gem](https://github.com/runar/capistrano-linked-files), but have an option for certain files just to be linked without uploading. I intend to use it for an sqlite database,
e.g. something like

```
set :link_only_files, fetch(:link_only_files, []).push('db/production.sqlite3')
```

(I know I should be using postgresql or mysql in production, this is just a temporary workaround).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up [patching the linked-files gem](https://github.com/dimidd/capistrano-linked-files/commit/47e37c36e02b8d1cfb2ca9c93853b0a317ad6ebd), and in `deploy.rb`:

```
set :link_only_files, [
  'db/production.sqlite3'
]
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push(
  'config/database.yml',
  [...]
  'db/production.sqlite3'
)

# Uploading only linked_files
before :deploy, 'linked_files:upload_files'
```

Admittedly, that's quite [damp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but I needed a quick solution.